# Issue with Opening task module in Teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

[image]

Getting above displayed error when trying to open a task module send over hero message card

Comment: What is your button _supposed_ to do? Does anything at all happen?

Comment: It is opening a task module. Nothing is happing on click. Getting above error on browser console

Comment: From the screen shot i could see that button title as open URL, Are you using Action as open URL?Could you please share the card JSON ? Also could you please go through the sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module/Bots/TeamsTaskModuleBot.cs#L78)?

Comment: **Thank You** for accepting answer, this will help others in the community with similar question. Could you please spare one min to let us know how we did by clicking on **[this feedback link](https://aka.ms/DevSupportFeedback)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the task module from the card the action type should be submit action. Here is the sample to open [Task module from card](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module/Bots/TeamsTaskModuleBot.cs#L78).